# Confusion About C++ Global Namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, scope

From my understanding, appending `::` to the front of a namespace refers to the global namespace, regardless of any using statements or parent namespaces. If that is the case, and I haven't mis-understood anything, then why does such code compile (at least in Visual Studio):

```
namespace Foo {
    namespace Bar {
        class X;
    }
}

using namespace Foo;
int main(void)
{
    ::Bar::X x;
}
```

Comment: Because a using directive imports everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`using namespace Foo;` brings all the contents of `namespace Foo` into the context of the current namespace.

Since `namespace Bar` is among the contents of `namespace Foo` and the current namespace on the line with the `using` statement is the global namespace, `namespace Bar` is brought into the context of the global namespace.

Comment: Ahh, okay thanks. I assumed that was what was happening, but I just wanted to make sure. I was really hoping `::` overrides using statements, but I guess we don't always get what we want :/

Comment: @Duncan `::` at the start of a statement is going to refer to scope resolution on the global namespace regardless of what `using` statements you've introduced. What do you mean by wanting it to "[override] using statements"?

Comment: @Duncan just to be clear `namespace K { using namespace Foo; }` puts the content of the `namespace Foo` under `K::`, that's all is happening here, except for the fact that the global namespace `::` is implied.

Comment: Take for example if I had put `using namespace Foo::Bar` instead. Then, if someone referred to `::X` in their code, then there is no easy way of knowing whether that was a reference to `Foo::Bar::X` or if there is a class `X` defined elsewhere outside of a namespace. I'm really just nit-picking at this point.

Comment: @Duncan But that's a problem you'll always encounter. Keep in mind that you can always use the fully qualified path to the type: `::Foo::Bar::X` - even if you have a `using namespace Foo::Bar;` statement.

Comment: @user2485710 Yes, and I'm saying that I wish `::` transcended that. That is to say that if I refer to `X`, then I'm allowing the compiler to use any class `X` defined in any namespace I have made available in the global namespace. For example, `Foo::Bar::X`. However, when I explicitly say `::X`, I instead want the class `X` not located in a namespace. Again, this is just how I wished using declarations worked

Comment: @Duncan namespaces are compile-time entities, meaning that they are more like a tool for the coder than something meaningful for the compiler; it's a way to organize what you have to write basically. There is no real solution to that kind of problem, you can be smart and so you can create another namespace like my `K` in the previous example so you know what's in there and when you just type `K::bar` and you know that `bar` can only be from that given list of namespaces, that's a way to limit the "pollution", you can also use this kind of technique to shorten the prefix of the namespace.

Comment: Again, I realize what I was doing wrong. I was just answering Timothy's question of what I meant when I said I wanted it to "[override] using statements." Additionally, your solution of using `K` is quite messy. Why not use namespace aliases in that case?